# How can I reach A bigger number of dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I can't reach a bigger number of dwellers, I have female dwellers, which are pregnant for more than three days. Usualy it takes just a few hours. The game is showing me that I have reached the maximum count of dwellers that is 50/50. I have also free rooms without any dwellers. What should I do?

Comment: Warning: once you build enough living quarters for 200 dwellers, the game will not allow you to build any more living quarters. Be careful about allowing your dwellers to become pregnant when you start getting close to this limit.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make more living quarters.  While you are at it, you may need need more power, food, and water to supply your additional dwellers.